# Linq query not selecting a list of fields

Tags: c#, linq

I have three linq queries, the first one just gets a list of assembly types which works fine. The second one I am having issues with. It is returning `0` results and I am not sure why.

Here is a query the first query that I use that gets reused:

```cs
      var types = (
        from assemblies in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        from type in assemblies.GetTypes()
        select type
      ).ToList();
```

Next I have this query which returns `0` results and I am not sure why:

```cs
      var injectors = (
        from type in types
        from attrs in type.GetCustomAttributes<InjectAttribute>()
        select attrs
      ).ToList();
```

The third query is almost exactly the same as the second query only it selects a different attribute. This one works:

```cs
      (
        from type in types
        from attrs in type.GetCustomAttributes<InjectableAttribute>()
        where attrs.ProvidedIn == ProvidedIn.Root
        select type
      ).ToList().ForEach(service => {
        var injector = injectors.Find(i => i.serviceType == service);
        if (injector != null) {
          var newService = Activator.CreateInstance(service);
          services.Add(newService);
        }
      })
```

I am not sure why the second query works and the third does not...

Here is how I am using the two:

```cs
[Injectable(ProvidedIn = ProvidedIn.Root)]
public class Item { }
```

```cs
public class Test {
  [Inject(typeof(Item))] Item item = null;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve, is in the foreach loop if one of the fields in the project has a `[Inject]` attribute used with a particular type, then create an instance, otherwise don't create an instance. This is for a reusable classlib, so an inject type may or may not be used on the project that is consuming the library. If it isn't being used I don't want to create an instance of the `[Injectable]`.

**Side note:** Is creating 3 separate Linq queries optimal, or I can I combine them into one query?

Comment: The first one does not provide you with what you expect because the attribute is set on a member, not a type

Comment: Your first query searches for *types* with this attribute. Are you trying to find type whose members have the attribute? You'll have to use `type.GetMembers()` and then `MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I understand you, then yes.

Comment: It's even combining your queries or writing them "separately" (at least in terms of results - but think about readability). But your actual code uses "ToList" between queries, so the generated compiled version would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Inject` is applied to members, not the type. To look for types whose members have that attribute you can use :

```
where type.GetMembers()
          .SelectAny(mi=>mi.GetCustomAttributes<InjectAttribute>())
          .Any()
```